# How do you add new functions to pre-existing java components?

Tags: java

To explain what I mean by this question I will use code examples below. Imagine you have this function.

```
private void fadeButton(JButton b, int timeToFade) {
    //Fade code goes here
}
```

How would you implement this as a function which could be run like

```
JButton b = new JButton("Press Me");
b.fadeButton(20000);
```

Where `fadeButton` now looks like

```
private void fadeButton(int timeToFade) {
    //Fade code goes here
}
```

Because the function is declared on the button itself.

Comment: you could extend the JButton class and add the method fadeButton to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **extend** JButton with a new class, thus inheriting JButton's methods and adding the ability to add your own code:

```
public class FadingButton extends JButton {

    //Constructors go here

    private void fadeButton(int timeToFade) {
        //Fade code goes here
    }
}
```

You could also **decorate** the JButton with another class:

```
public class JButtonDecorator {
    private JButton btn;

    //Constructor here

    private void fadeButton(int timeToFade) {
        //Fade code goes here, hiding the held button
    }

    //getter and setter method for button
}
```

Or, if you want lots of different ways to affect your UI, you can make a **utility** class, similar to above:

```
//You could use a factory pattern to make this a singleton instead of having static methods
public abstract class UIUtils {

    private UIUtils{} //Don't instantiate this class

    public static void fadeComponent(JComponent toFade) {
        //Fade code goes here
    }

    //Other static utility methods
}
```

**Edit:** Making use of these patterns. The extended class is self-explanatory and an example of simple inheritance, so it's just a matter of `JButton btn = new FadingButton();` for example. Here are the others:

To use the **decorator**, instantiate it at the same scope as the button you're using now. For example:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton();
//Customize button and add to UI
JButtonDecorator jbDec = new JButtonDecorator(myButton);

jbDec.fadeButton(20000);
```

Although the button is a field of the decorator, it will otherwise behave normally in your UI. The decorator just wraps the class with useful methods such as the `fadeButton` method.

To use the **utility** class, there are two ways. One is two make an **abstract** class with **static** methods (as above), some consider it bad form but it's good for simple programs:

```
UIUtils.fadeComponent(myButton); //It's just that simple!
//The UIUtils class itself is never instantiated.
//All the methods are static, so no instances are needed.
```

Or if you want a more advanced method, make your utility class a **singleton**. This changes the utility class to this:

```
public class UIUtils {

    UIUtils singleton;

    private UIUtils{} //Don't instantiate this class publicly

    public static UIUtils getInstance() {
        if(singleton==null) //This is the first time the method is called
             singleton = new UIUtils();
        return singleton; //Return the one instance of UIUtils
    }

    public void fadeComponent(JComponent toFade) {
        //Fade code goes here
    }

    //Other utility methods
}
```

Then you would declare your `UIUtils` object at class level to use across your UI:

```
UIUtils uiUtil = UIUtils.getInstance();
```

And somewhere in your code:

```
uiUtil.fadeComponent(myButton);
```

This pattern is more efficient with memory and is more object-oriented, but I don't personally find it very suitable for utility classes.

Comment: Could you edit this to show how each one is implemented? For example the utility class?

Comment: Implemented to what extent? If you mean the code to fade the button, I don't have the Swing experience to know that.

Comment: Oh no. I know how to fade a button. That was just a name I chose for the example method. I mean how do you implement `JButtonDecorator` and `UIUtils`. For example how do you implement an abstract class?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you create a derived class:

`public JFadableButton extends JButton`

This will contain the method `private void fadeButton(int timeToFade)`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: you don't.

Longer answer:

You can't do that in Java directly (adding methods to a class outside of the source code of that class). That might be different in other languages, like Kotlin offers "something" like that.

In java, you have to make detours, for example by turning to the [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern.

And just for the record: I didn't mention the simple "you can extend that class" because I read your question as "how do I add methods to JButton directly". But of course, creating your own class that extends JButton allows you to add methods; but of course, they only exist on objects of your derived class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class which extends `JButton`, and then add any method that could help you achieve what you want. But that's an exemple, there is many ways to achieve this.

Ps, don't set this method as private if you want to use it somewhere else than inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way I think think of. You have already got it. But just use this method:

```
private void fadeButton(int timeToFade) {
    //Fade code goes here
}
```

This is assuming you already have the code for the fade, do you? I think this one is the one you should use. You don't need the button to be a parameter. When you want to call the method to fade the button, just put it in the `ActionListener`. So after you have the `ActionListener` for the button, do the following: `btnName.fadeButton(timeToFade);`

Here is how to code the ActionListener:

```
btnHome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```